# Setting up a website to sync data with android phone

Tags: java, android

I am writing an android application that requires a large amount of bandwith to collect data and then process this data. doing this induvidually on each phone would be quite a waste.(I have the code already and it works as a standalone java application). So i decided to upload this data onto a website and let the users sync their phone with the website. But i have no clue as to how to go about this. (I already have a website which is hosted on my home computer). Would anyone know how to go about this. are there any tutorials for doing this?( Since i already have my code in a standalone java application is it possible to put up this application on my server in java only since i am relatively new to php and wouldnt know the required code to accomplish this task.)

Comment: I don't know how to set up your home computer as a server but I used Googles App Engine: http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest thing to do is take your standalone Java application, modify it for server usage and run it on an internet-connected server (e.g. rent a small Amazon EC2 instance).

There isn't all that much difference between a standalone Java application and a server application - they are both applications running inside a JVM instance that you can launch from the command line, the only difference is how you interact with them. So instead of a GUI, you'll want to provide some kind of server-side API that clients can connect to.

Probably the easiest thing to do is use something based on the Servlet API.... you can use this both to provide a REST-style API for your client devices as well as provide web pages for administration / viewing the collected data etc.